# split export mongodb to json

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a lots of data in my mongodb and I want to export to the entire data to json where each file no bigger than 500 kb (smaller files) such as:

```
exported_file.1.json
exported_file.2.json
...
```

I know that I can use `mongoexport` to export data from mongodb to json but it will result one big json file, so is there a way to export entire  mongodb to muliple small json file so that each file would be below 500kb?

Comment: what is the reason for this? Do you need each chunk to be a valid json? Also what would you do if the document is 16 Mb which is valid mongo doc?

Comment: the reason is the internet connection not great, uploading bigger files my cause failed to upload; and yes i need each to be valid json ;  for the last question what do you mean by valid mongo doc ?

Comment: Does this need to be done using mongodb prompt or can Java code be used?

Comment: anything that works as I got stuck figuring this out, btw thanks

Comment: Can you check my answer. I believe it solves the problem.

Comment: @GoranStoyanov thanks forgot to accept he answer

Comment: for anyone looking for this answer another way to do it to split the extracted, then convert it to zip then split it. it may need a lot of work, but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a shell script and via the mongoexport options `--skip` and `--limit` so basically limit the number of documents in each file and use skip as an offset.

Something like this if your total is let say 5 milion records:

```
limit=10000;
skip=0;
for i in {1..500}; do mongoexport --db your_db --collection your_collection --type=json --fields "the fields you want to include in the export" --out exported_file.${i}.json -v --skip ${skip} --limit ${limit} --quiet;
let skip=$((skip+limit));
done
```